# Using eigenvectors to find the general solution from a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{bmatrix}-13&40&-48\\-8&23&-24\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}

Consider the matrix above. This corresponds to 
\begin{align*}
x_{1}'&=-13x_{1}+40x_{2}-48x_{3}\\
x_{2}'&=-8x_{1}+23x_{2}-24x_{3}\\
x_{3}'&=3x_{3}
\end{align*}

What I want to do is use eigenvectors to find the general solution. First I computed $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. From this I got my eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 7$ and $\lambda = 3$ (this one is multiplicity 2).

Next I would find $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ where $x$ is the eigenvector I am looking for. For $\lambda=7$, my eigenvector came out to be,

\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}

So no problems here. On the other hand, I had some difficulties for when $\lambda = 3$. The matrix I would be solving for is

\begin{bmatrix} -16&40&-48&0 \\ -8&20&-24&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}

When I do this I obtain,

\begin{bmatrix} 1&-2.5&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}

so $$x_{1} -2.5x_{2}+3x_{3} = 0.$$

From here I am not sure how to get the two eigenvectors. The computer told me they are,

\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}

but I have no idea how to get these from what I have remaining. Also how would I write the general solution?

Comment: You have $x_{1} = 2.5x_{2}-3x_{3}$. You just want to pick values such that you have two linearly independent eigenvectors. Do you see how the two eigenvectors (choose values randomly - eigenvectors are not unique) satisfy this relation? You have two free variables, $x_2$ and $x_3$. Pick them randomly so you get two linearly independent eigenvectors - they can be anything as long as that condition is satisfied.

Comment: So the eigenvectors the computer generated don't necessarily have to be the eigenvectors I write down? Those are just two out of infinitely many of them?

Comment: That is correct. However, an eigenvector can never be a zero vector. So, you could have chosen $x_2 = \dfrac{2}{5}, x_3 = 0$, so $x_1 = 1$, for example.

Comment: If you think about it, $Av_1 = 3v_1$ and $Av_2 = 3v_2$, so really if I let $\omega = \lambda v_1 + \mu v_2$, then $A\omega = A(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2) = A\lambda v_1 + A\mu v_2 =\lambda Av_1 + \mu A v_2 = 3\lambda v_1 + 3\mu v_2 = 3(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2) = 3 \omega$. Does this help? (So long as $\omega \neq 0$ ofc)

Comment: Thanks. That does help. My only other question here is, if I have all the eigenvectors, what would the general solution look like?

Comment: Since you can find three linearly independent eigenvectors (you have a repeated eigenvalue - so this may not always be true and you might have to resort to generalized eigenvectors and Jordan Forms), it is $$X(t) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3 $$

Comment: Thank you so much Moo. I appreciate it and have learned a lot here. I have just one question. With the problem I am working with, can I write it in the form above that you just stated or do I have to do more? I just wanted to double check. I have seen examples of a defective matrix and it looks like more has to be done for the general solution. Didn't know if I had a defective matrix here.

Comment: You found three LI eigenvectors - so it is **not** a defective matrix - you have a diagonalizable matrix. The form I show is how you would write it out. You can show the eigenvalue and eigenvectors in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Solving the System of linear Equations

So it seems you want to solve the system of equations
$$
Ax =
\begin{pmatrix}-13&40&-48\\-8&23&-24\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \\ x'_3 \end{pmatrix} 
= x'
$$
Where the $x'$ is given and the $x_j$ are looked for.

You would normally solve this by calculating the inverse of $A$, since then
$$
x = A^{-1} x'
$$
But let's say you really want to solve this by using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. You have already determined both of these, providing the change of base matrix $S$ which contains the eigenvectors
$$
S =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & -3 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which accomplishes
$$
S^{-1} A S = D =
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We can now solve for $x$. Using the above,
\begin{align*}
x &= A^{-1} x' 
\\&= (SDS^{-1})^{-1} x'
\\&= SD^{-1}S^{-1} x'
\\&=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & -3 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{7}
\end{pmatrix}
S^{-1} x'
\end{align*}
As you can see, we do not yet have the solution, since we don't know what $S^{-1}$ looks like. So what's left to do is: calculate the inverse of $S$, multiply everything and be done.

(So whatever method you use, you have to calculate the inverse of *some* matrix)

---

### Getting the Eigenvectors

To determine the last two eigenvectors, you got the equation
$$
x_1 - 2.5 x_2 + 3 x_3 = 0
$$
whose solutions $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ you want to find. What the equation tells us is, that if we are given two of the variables, the third one (for example $x_1$) will be determined.
$$
x_1 = 2.5 x_2 - 3 x_3
$$
Thus the solutions can be written as
$$
( 2.5 x_2 - 3 x_3 , x_2 , x_3 )
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
2.5 x_2 - 3 x_3 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
x_2
\begin{pmatrix}
2.5 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+
x_3
\begin{pmatrix}
- 3 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
~~~~~~~ \text{with} ~~ x_2 , x_3 \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Any solution of this form is an eigenvector. Since you need two eigenvectors, you take two different solutions. For example the solutions with
$$
(x_2,x_3) = (2,0) ~~~\text{or}~~~ (0,1)
$$
Which yield the eigenvectors that the computer gave you.